# d3 does not support cross-domain request even though after using SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, simplehttpserver

I want to load a tsv file from a specific directory which is different from the d3 directory.
My d3 script resides under `/home/meet/workspace/d3_test/scripts` and SimpleHTTPServer running at "/" root.

```
d3.tsv("http://localhost:8888/home/meet/data/data.tsv",function(error,data){ 
    console.log("fetching data.tsv file "+error+data);
    });
```

Throwing an error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/home/meet/data/data.tsv 200 OK 5ms (in red color)
fetching data.tsv file [object XMLHttpRequest] undefined
```

Note:-

1. Tried passing `file:///` which is not supported
2. [Mike mentions link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#installing) with SimpleHTTPServer
3. Also, I don't want to edit my browser settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up running server at root `"/"` with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`

accessing my html file from localhost

for e.g. - `http://localhost:8888/home/meet/workspace/d3_test/scripts/data_fetch.html`

and my tsv file is on following location

```
http://localhost:8888/home/meet/data/data.tsv
```

Note:- Setting up your SimpleHTTPServer at root `"/"` helps you to fetch any file from any directory at given security cost.

EDIT:-

Unfortunately, SimpleHTTPServer is really that simple that it does not allow any customization, especially not of the headers it sends. You can however create a simple HTTP server yourself, using most of SimpleHTTPServer and just add that desired header.

Simply create a file simple-cors-http-server.py (or whatever) and put the following inside:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import BaseHTTPServer

class CORSRequestHandler (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers (self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BaseHTTPServer.test(CORSRequestHandler, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
```

Then you can do python simple-cors-http-server.py and it will launch your modified server which will set the CORS header for every response.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like there's enough evidence to conclude that this is a cross-domain problem. The console log should be able to provide more details, but I'd guess that the problem is that the server isn't setting the mime type correctly for tab-separated values. According to the [d3.js source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/dsv/tsv.js) for `tsv` files the mime type should be `"text/tab-separated-values"`. Should be easy enough to check this in the console.

Comment: When I am loading from same directory its already has mime type set to "text/tab-separated-values" and same with localhost server as well.