# how to install python for using d3 charts at windows

Tags: d3.js, cmd

I have to use [d3](http://d3js.org/) graph at my web page. I never worked with d3. That's why, I'm facing some problem using it. Basically, I've to work at dropbox folder. So, my clients can see the worked file locally at their browser. Consider, I put a d3 chart at file.html file and my folder structure is like this

> D:\Projects\Dropbox (Company)\MyName\FolderName\file.html

But, I saw that to run and see/show d3 examples I need run web server or run a python server. So, I've downloaded `Python 3.4.1` and installed by double click. It's installed at this directory: `C:\Python34`

After that, I tried to follow d3's documentation for installing python server. So, I opened my cmd and type:

> python -m http.server 8888 &

But, it gives me this error:

[image]

So, my question is:

1. How can I install python web server?
2. After installing that web server, is it possible see the d3 chart via this link: `file:///D:/Projects/Dropbox (Company)/MyName/FolderName/file.html` or I've put my files inside htdocs and run via `http://localhost/folderName/file.html` (I don't want to put files inside htdocs. It'll be tough for my clients see the output of the files directly from their pc)?

If it can't be seen without putting inside htdocs folder, I may find solution for running d3.js locally without installing any additional software/server(though I've found this type of solution for some d3.js chart but not for all). Thanks in advance and please don't mind if it's a lame question. Basically, it's my first day working with d3.js and I'm only ameture level skilled with javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

OK, browsers are designed with security in mind, by default they don't let scripts go and grab a file from anywhere for very good reasons.  They allow you to grab a file from the server or through requests.  So to share your work with your client you will either need to use a hosting service - I would recommend [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/), design your visualisation so it doesn't require any external data or provide instructions on how to disable browser security. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570640/d3-does-not-support-cross-domain-request-even-though-after-using-simplehttpserve), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721945/very-simple-tutorial-example-of-d3-js-not-working) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/WD46vb-1PNk).

On python, in many cases python is already installed on people machines, so running a server from python shouldn't be an issue.  All you have to do (on a windows machine) is launch your command prompt navigate to your directory and start your python server.  Then open a browser and navigate to the localhost.  Please note that python needs to be set as an environmental variable (i.e. your system path), the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) might help you here.

Comment: I am not sure what I'll do. But, there is another person using MAC and he can see the d3 eample from his MAC browser via this link file:///D:/Projects/Dropbox (Company)/MyName/FolderName/file.html
If he can see, why I can't see! Is it because only I'm running Windows? If it's, there should be an way seeing that from any directory at Windows..

Comment: if you want to use dropbox, which sounds like a good solution to our problem, try [this ](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/host-websites-with-dropbox) link.